# Can't understand the Exception when using dynamic with generic collection in .net4

Tags: dynamic, .net-4.0, generic-collections

check the code below please:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    IList<dynamic> items = new List<dynamic>();
    items.Add(3);
    items.Add("solid");
    dynamic i = new ExpandoObject();
    items.Add(i); //System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Add'
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

is this a bug in "dynamic" mechanism?

Comment: +1 wish I knew more about the complexity of the dynamic binding. I just tried this and it appears that `items.Add(new ExpandoObject());` is fine, but `items.Add((dynamic)new ExpandoObject());` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug (or is it a feature request?):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534288/ilist-dynamic-cannot-call-a-method-add-without-casting

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    IList<dynamic> items = new List<dynamic>();
    items.Add(3);
    items.Add("solid");
    dynamic i = new ExpandoObject();
    items.Add((object) i); // type-cast dynamic object
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thx，trick works fine,but I like simplicity and explicitness than trick in my code :)