# 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' when using 'dynamic' and 'ExpandoObject'

Tags: .net, exception, dynamic, expandoobject

Say that I have a class, Foo, looking something like this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<dynamic>();
    }
    public IList<dynamic> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

The interface IFoo looks like:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IList<dynamic> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I do the following:

```
IFoo foo = new Foo();
dynamic a = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
a.Prop = 10000;
dynamic b = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
b.Prop = "Some Text";
foo.Bars.Add(a); // Throws an 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' - exception!!!!!
foo.Bars.Add(b); // Same here!!!!!
```

What am I doing wrong here?????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't understand the Exception when using dynamic with generic collection in .net4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996491/cant-understand-the-exception-when-using-dynamic-with-generic-collection-in-ne)

Comment: Would you post the exception that you are getting?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a known dynamic binding [issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20130609133940/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534288/ilist-dynamic-cannot-call-a-method-add-without-casting).

Here are some work arounds.

**Use `ICollection<dynamic>` instead:**

```
void Main()
{
    IFoo foo = new Foo();
    dynamic a = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    a.Prop = 10000;
    dynamic b = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    b.Prop = "Some Text";
    foo.Bars.Add(a);
    foo.Bars.Add(b); 
}

public interface IFoo
{
    ICollection<dynamic> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<dynamic>();
    }

    public ICollection<dynamic> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

**Or straight up `List<dynamic>`:**

```
public interface IFoo
{
    List<dynamic> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<dynamic>();
    }

    public List<dynamic> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

**Or use `dynamic foo`:**

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic foo = new Foo();
    dynamic a = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    a.Prop = 10000;
    dynamic b = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    b.Prop = "Some Text";
    foo.Bars.Add(a);
    foo.Bars.Add(b); 
}
```

**Or don't dynamic bind `add`, by casting to `object`:**

```
void Main()
{
    IFoo foo = new Foo();
    dynamic a = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    a.Prop = 10000;
    dynamic b = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    b.Prop = "Some Text";
    foo.Bars.Add((object)a); 
    foo.Bars.Add((object)b); 
}
```

**Or be more expressive using a third party framework like my impromptu interface with [ActLike](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageBasic) & [Prototype Builder Syntax](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageBuilder) (in nuget).**

```
using ImprmoptuInterface;
using Dynamitey;
void Main()
{
    dynamic New = Builder.New<ExpandoObject>();

    IFoo foo = Impromptu.ActLike(
                   New.Foo(
                       Bars: New.List(
                                 New.Obj(Prop:10000),
                                 New.Obj(Prop:"Some Text")
                             )
                       )
                   );
}

public interface IFoo
{
    IList<dynamic> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne! In my case, using List<dynamic>.Add instead of IList<dynamic>.Add seemed the best option. The containing function returned IList<dynamic> as before.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this subverts your particular use case, but:

Try explicitly casting `Bars` to `System.Collections.IList`.

```
((System.Collections.IList)foo.Bars).Add(a);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468123/364

Alternatively, just redefine `Bars` as `IList` rather than `IList<dynamic>` in your interface + class.