# Method calling inside a foreach with dynamic list causes RuntimeBinderException "does not contain a definition for 'Add'"

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

I like to understand how dynamic keyword works in this following code. I found a number of posts that talks about how calling Add() on IList cause  RuntimeBinderException, but doesn't quite explain why the following code does not work:

```
    [TestFixture]
public class TestDynamicOfIList
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        dynamic d1 = new ClassA();
        dynamic d2 = new ClassA();

        List<dynamic> dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();

        dynamicList.Add(d1);
        dynamicList.Add(d2);

        ClassGroup group = new ClassGroup();

        foreach (dynamic dynamicClassA in dynamicList)
        {
            // using var will fail during runtime! Need to use explicit type
            var sameObject = DoNothing(dynamicClassA);
            group.ClassAList.Add(sameObject);
        }
    }

    private ClassA DoNothing(dynamic classA)
    {
        return classA;
    }

    public class ClassA
    {
    }

    public class ClassGroup
    {
        public IList<ClassA> ClassAList { get;  } = new List<ClassA>();
    }
}
```

}

In the above code, the ClassGroup.ClassAList property has a defined class 'ClassA' for the generic IList<>, I can't see why the compiler failed to do type checking, nor the it fails during runtime.

Here a couple of similar questions that I found on StackOverflow:

[How to create a List with a dynamic object type C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600810/how-to-create-a-list-with-a-dynamic-object-type-c-sharp)

[Does not contain a definition for "Add"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327034/does-not-contain-a-definition-for-add)

**Why when I use `var sameObject` it will not work it, but using `ClassA sameObject` it works fine?** It seems to think that the type of `sameObject` variable is dynamic, when the method `DoNothing()` clearly returns `ClassA`

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9382130/573218

Comment: Actually, after consideration, it is not an exact duplicate.  The linked question does explain why sameObject is determined to be dynamic by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9382130/573218) answers why `sameObject` is determined to be `dynamic` by the compiler.

A simpler example to demonstrate this would be:

```
dynamic d1 = new ClassA();
var s = DoNothing(d1);
IList<ClassA> c = new List<ClassA>();
c.Add(s);
```

The reason the `Add` to the `IList` doesn't work seems to come down to overload resolution.  The runtime can't find an overload of `Add` on `IList` to use, so it throws an exception. You already know that if you explicitly state the type that it works, so that is a possible solution to the problem.

Interestingly, if you use `ICollection<ClassA>` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15920844/573218)), it does work, so it seems to be an issue with the `IList` interface:

```
dynamic d1 = new ClassA();
var s = DoNothing(d1);
ICollection<ClassA> c = new List<ClassA>();
c.Add(s);
```

Comment: It also works, when Using `IList` and `Insert` instead of `Add`. `Insert` is directly declared in `IList`. So, it seems that runtime resolution of method calls cannot find methods in an interface inherited from another interface, probably because interface inheritance does not include implementation inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

> I would really like to know why using "var sameObject" will not work

You are trying to call `Add` on `IList` and that is why it is not working. You can fix the issue 2 ways:

**Fix 1**

Call `ToList()` and then add the object.

```
group.ClassAList.ToList().Add(sameObject);
```

**Fix 2**

Return `List` from your property:

```
public class ClassGroup
{
    public List<ClassA> ClassAList { get;  } = new List<ClassA>();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works fine if they do `ClassA sameObject = DoNothing(dynamicClassA)` I think the real root of this question is why does `var` infer `dynamic` instead of `ClassA` as the type for `sameObject`

Comment: @JohnKoerner no it does not infer dynamic. It infers `ClassA`

Comment: According to the VS IDE, it is inferring dynamic: http://imgur.com/zel8syF

Comment: My VS IDE shows `ClassA` like I said earlier: http://imgur.com/a/pcN2T

Comment: The type is listed as dynamic (look at the right column), the value is the ToString(), which shows the class name.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: This is not talking about runtime, but about compile time.